# visual studio response flush does not cause file downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I write the following code in visual studio and when I run it, it does not download any file. What is the possible error? I was using iisexpress as the developing server.

```
 private void ExportMASummaryToExcel(int companyid, int year, string lang = "en-US")
            {
                try {
                    string requestUri = String.Format("Report/ExportMASummaryReport?companyID={0}&year={1}&lang={2}"
                        , companyid
                        , year
                        , lang
                        );
    
                   
                    int? timeout = 
  Util.TryToConvertToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WEB_CLIENT_TIMEOUT_FOR_DATA_EXTRACT"]);
                   
                    using (WebClient client = new Common.FXWebClient(timeout))
                    {
                        byte[] content = client.DownloadData(_sustainabilityServiceURL + requestUri);
                        Page.Response.Clear();
                        Page.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                        Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Data.xlsx");
                        Page.Response.BinaryWrite(content);
                        //Page.Response.OutputStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
                        Page.Response.Flush();
                        Page.Response.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (ApplicationException ex)
                {
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    
                }
    
                try
                {
                    Page.Response.End();
                }
                catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException) { }
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?  Does content contain any data?  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if the response status is 200 OK or a 400/500 error.

Comment: I see the content is having non zero length.

Comment: in Firefox inspect console, I see this message 
```Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.```

Comment: The firefox message just says the response is bad with no details.  If you have a working application that gets good response from server you can compare the good and the bad.  Right now we do not know if the format of the response is bad, the connection never completed, or the connection completed but query was not formatted properly.